# Parse dashboard issue - form tampered with

Tags: node.js, docker, parse-server, parse-dashboard

When I log in am getting prompt as "form tampered with"

```
I am unable to fix this issue.

Please let me know what I am missing in this config.
parser-dashabord - @1.2.0
parse-server - @3.1.2

Parse-Dashboard js File

var options = {
      allowInsecureHTTP: true,
      cookieSessionSecret:'thisismysecretkey'
    };

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://parseserver:1337/parse",
    "appId": "mobile-apps",
    "masterKey": "**",
    "appName": "First App"
  }],
  "users": [{
    "user": "user1",
    "pass": "pass",
    "apps": [{
      "appId": "mobile-apps"
    }]
  }],
  "trustProxy": true,
  "useEncryptedPasswords": false
}, options);
```

Is there anything I missed with the config in parse-server configuration file?

Comment: Please add code of config file so one can help.

Comment: I added the config file of parse-dashboard.

Comment: Does it work locally?  I actually JUST ran into this myself when deploying to Heroku and utilizing Node Clustering.  Is that what you are doing?  Without clustering the * cookieSessionSecret* addition resolved the issue... not sure what to try next myself

Comment: How are you running app? I mean if you are running with multiple instances with pm2 then it will throw that error because request may be sent to other instance causing some csrf validation.